# jquery add class and removeclass between delay

Tags: jquery

I would like to loop through all my .selector class elements and each time I would like it to wait x seonds before it adds class and run it's queue function

```
    $(".selector").each(function (i) {
        i = 1 + i;
        // like .delay(1000*i) before next event

        $(this).addClass('show').delay(2000*i).queue(function( next ){
            $(this).find('.achildselector').addClass('class');
            next();
        });

    });
```

so in psuedo code. Add class after x*i seconds and after x*i seconds add another class for each selector

Comment: It's really not clear exactly what you're trying to do, but if you want to run this logic every X seconds, wrap this code block in a `setInterval()` call.

Comment: right I can wrap that in a SetInterval with like 1000*i but that wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly. you want to add a class to each of the parents with interval, and within each parent add a class to child with an interval.
Something like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".selector").each(function(index, element) {
    var i = index + 1;
    setInterval(function() {
      $(element).addClass('show');
      $(element).find('.achildselector').each(function(spanIndex, span) {
        var j = spanIndex + 1;
        setInterval(function() {
          $(span).addClass('class');

        }, j * 1000);
      });
    }, i * 2000);

  });
});
```

```css
.selector {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.show {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

span {
  color: red;
}

.class {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selector">
  Div 1
  <span class="achildselector">child 1</span>
  <span class="achildselector">child 2</span>
  <span class="achildselector">child 3</span>
</div>
<div class="selector">
  Div 2
  <span class="achildselector">child 1</span>
  <span class="achildselector">child 2</span>
  <span class="achildselector">child 3</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you are loosing reference to the elements on every iteration and that is why you could use the [closure](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp) to hold the values, like this:

```
$(".selector").each(function (i) {
    i = 1 + i;
    // like .delay(1000*i) before next event

    (function(e, delay) {
        return function() {
            e.addClass('show');
            setTimeout(function() {
                e.find('.achildselector').addClass('class');
            }, delay);
        }
    })($(this), 1000*i);
});
```